# Wine emulated Epic Games store cannot log in using Google account

Tags: login, wine, games, playonlinux

Hello Ubuntu community

I am new to Linux gaming, and I want to install Rocket league on Ubuntu. Because Rocket League is Windows only, I need to use Wine to emulate it. Rocket league is (as far as I know) only availible in the Epic Games store, so I installed it using Wine and Lutris. Now, I need to log in the Epic Games store, and my Epic account is linked to my Google account. So I press "Log in with Google", and normally, a web browser will open and ask me for my Google account. Now, absolutly nothing happens, just tells me I need to continue login in my browser.

Do you know what is going on and how I can log in?

Thanks

Irsu85

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Also, wine is not an emulator.

Comment: I am facing same issue in Ubuntu LTS 22.04.3 version. not able to login in Epic games because browser is not getting launched. Please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was a distro issue and in Kubuntu and Pop OS it works fine.